# ¿Como puedo crear una URL Blob para una imagen o video?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo crear una URL Blob para una imagen o video que este en mi servidor, aquí tengo un código pero es para cuando el usuario elige el archivo desde su computadora.

Comment: Un blob ya es un recurso en la nube y cuentas con la url para la descarga, si esta en tu servidor debes crear un servicio digamos un web api para subir el archivo y pasarlo al cliente. Es decir desde el sitio usas la llamada al servidor y cargas el archivo el archivo al sitio y ese archivo lo descarga el usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Como mencione en el comentario, debes crear una manera de subir tus archivos para exponerlos como un blob en tu sitio, ahora para archivos pequeños digamos menos de 5 megas puedes usar la funcion blob de javascript.

Ejemplo para exponer una imagen como blob, en tu html agregas un tag de imagen

```
<body onload="cargarImagen()">
    <img id="imagen">
</body>
```

en tu javascript agregas el metodo:

```
function cargarImagen() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "imagenes/imagen1.jpeg");
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    xhr.onload = function(error) {
        var blob = new Blob([xhr.response]);
        var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(blobUrl);
        document.getElementById("imagen").src = blobUrl;
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Nota1: el codigo solo es para subir el elemento falta agregar codigo para
       descarga, digamos un boton de descarga.

Nota2:  por cada blob, usas memoria de tu sitio, por cada llamada a tu sitio para descargar incrementas el trafico, por eso para blobs locales solo es recomendable para archivos pequeños y pocos usuarios. Para archivos grandes y pocos usuarios, se podria utilizar un Web Worker y subir el archivo por partes, pero esto es algo mas complejo.